# MySQL distinct query, result into another table

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have two field lat and lng in tbl1.
I just like to select only the unique numbers from both field and I like to place the result in tbl2 in the fields with the same name lat and lng.

Sorry about my inaccuracy.

Tbl1 is a square grid of coordinates, that is, the latitude coordinate is the same on each row of the grid, and the longitude coordinate is the same on each column, respectively. So there are as many different longitude and latitude coordinates in the result. Example - if grid is 100 x 100, tbl1 has 10000 rows and result table tbl2 has 100 rows or even smaller grid 2 x 2:

```
tbl1:  
lat,lng,some more fields,..  
65.123456,24.123456,..  
65.123456,24.123567,..
65.123567,24.123456,..  
65.123567,24.123567,..
tbl2:  
lat,lng  
65.123456,24.123456  
65.123567,24.123567
```

I have tried the following:

```
insert into tbl2 (lat, lng) select distinct lat, lng from tbl1;
```

and I cant use

```
.. select distinct lat from tbl1 union select distinct lng from tbl1;
```

because it only returns one field.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  Do you know how to use `DISTINCT` in a `SELECT` query?  Do you know how to use `SELECT` in an `INSERT` query?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When posting any SQL questions, it is important to provide a small sample of rows from each related table. In your case, provide a sample from `tbl1` and a sample of what the result in `tbl2` should be, given the sample from `tbl1`. You should also show us any code you have already tried, as we are happy to help where stuck but few contributors are willing to provide free coding service with no prior effort.

Answer (score 1):

An insert-select statement with the `distinct` keyword should do the trick:

```
INSERT INTO tbl2
SELECT DISTINT lat, lng
FROM   tbl1
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a detour to this problem at the principle of how to eat an elephant - a piece at a time - ie. with additional two temporary table.

```
create temporary table t1 (
  id int not null auto_increment primary key ,
  lat double(10,6) not null unique
)  ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
create temporary table t2 (
  id int not null auto_increment primary key ,
  lng double(10,6) not null unique
) ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

insert into t1 (lat) select distinct lat from tbl1;
insert into t2 (lng) select distinct lng from tbl1;

insert into tbl2 select null as id, lat, lng from t1 cross join t2 where t1.id=t2.id;

drop table t1;
drop table t2;
```

Maybe some more simple and sophisticated way could be found here?